# How to install analytica into mathematica?

Tags: packages, installation

I have come upon the following automated theorem prover made in mathematica, called Analytica. 
https://github.com/langit/analytica

I'm not exactly sure how to use it correctly. I tried setting analytica-master as the directory and running index.all, but it gives me a constant stream of errors. How can I install and use this package correctly?

Answer (score 1):

So i tried it and at least for MMA11 there are bugs.

In the Readme is shown how to load it

```
<<index.all
```

This should do the job. But that just introduces many errormessages for me. They get thrown by getting

```
<<prover.M;
<<lemmas.m;
```

sadly the most intersting ones.

You should contact the authors for help.